# How to restrict numbers in a textfield using jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

I want to restrict upto two numbers in my textbox.But when a point(ie a dot) appears the restriction must have to release and after the point it can extend upto 4.

ie if i try to type 100,enable the restriction and restrict to type only upto 10.but if i type 10.303 enable me ...

I am new to jquery.I tried a lot of ways but it wont works.any help will be highly appreciable

Comment: have you tried any?include in OP

Comment: yes..but it wont works..using maxlength i can restrict using html.but how to loop it for the dot (.) symbol

Answer (score 2):

below is the solution for it:

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Luga5yo4/

```
$(function () {
    $(".txt").on("keyup", function(event) {
        // don't handle backspace, delete, pgup/pgdn, home/end, or arrow keys:
        if (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46 || event.keyCode >= 33 && event.keyCode <= 40) return false;

        var currentEl = $(this);
        var value = $(currentEl).val();

        // remove letters...
        value = value.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, "");

        var hasDecPlace = value.match(/\./);

        // separate integer from decimal places:
        var pieces = value.split('.');
        var integer = pieces[0].replace('-', '');
        var decPlaces = ""
        if (pieces.length > 1)
        {
            pieces.shift();
            decPlaces = pieces.join('').replace('-', '');
        }

        // handle numbers greater than 99.9999... :
    if (integer > 99.9999 || integer === 99.9999 && parseInt(decPlaces) > 0)
        {
            integer = "99";
            decPlaces = getZeroedDecPlaces(decPlaces);
            alert("number must be between 0 and 99");
        } // ...and less than 0:
        else if (parseInt(integer) < 0)
        {
            integer = "0";
            decPlaces = getZeroedDecPlaces(decPlaces);
            alert("number must be between 0 and 99");
        }



// handle more than four decimal places:
        if (decPlaces.length > 4)
        {
            decPlaces = decPlaces.substr(0, 4);
            alert("number cannot have more than four decimal places");
        } 


        var newVal = hasDecPlace ? integer + '.' + decPlaces : integer;

        $(currentEl).val(newVal);
    });

    function getZeroedDecPlaces(decPlaces) {
        if (decPlaces === '') return '';
        else if (decPlaces.length === 1) return '0';
        else if (decPlaces.length >= 2) return '00';
    }
});
```